# Multiple array to json error django

Tags: python, json, django

'list' object has no attribute '_meta'**i try to merge 2 object in array after i can this but i can't return json response**

```
def regions(request):
    result_set  = []
    for u in Regions.objects.all()[:100]:
        if 'a' in u.country:
            result_set.append([u ,Subregions.objects.filter(region_id=u.id)])
    data = serializers.serialize('json', result_set)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

error code:
AttributeError at /
'list' object has no attribute '_meta'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`serializers.serialize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/) accepts an iterable that yields model isntances as the second parameter.

But the `result_set` is a list of list of models. You need to adjust the code to yield model instances.

Comment: after this; <Subregions: Subregions object> is not JSON serializable

result_set  = []
    for u in Regions.objects.all()[:100]:
        if 'a' in u.country:
            result_set.append([u.country, list(Subregions.objects.filter(region_id=u.id))])
    data = json.dumps(result_set)
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')

Comment: i get same error that is is not JSON serializable.
Same ruby code doesn't get error code that @result_set.push([c.country,City.where(region_id:c.id).take(20)])

Comment: @user3036749, how about this? `result_set.append(u); result_set.extend(Subregions.objects.filter(region_id=u.id))`. edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: result_set.append(u)TypeError at /
<Regions: Regions object> is not JSON serializable

Comment: @user3036749, Could you show me the full traceback by uploading it somewhere (like pastebin)

Comment: @user3036749, I think this is related to dependency between model. Check this out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/serialization/#dependencies-during-serialization

Comment: i think problem isn't serialization becase if i add 'values_list()' last of query, code is run

Answer (score 0):

Basically as its a list of models, it is not able to serialize. And most probably your model has a foreign key relation too.

To solve this you can have a method in the model called as_json(). Which converts the model into a dictionary.

Overall your main target should be to convert the model into dictionary.